# Session is not read in multiple controllers in cakephp

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I'm using Sessions in a cakephp app but it looks like the session that I've set up is not shared between the various controllers that I'm using. So lets say I have

PagesController

```
      public $components = array( 'Email', 'Session', 'RequestHandler', 'Cookie'); 
      //this is pages/home
      public function home(){

         $this->Session->write("bunny", "123456");
         debug($this->Session->read("bunny"));
      }
```

PersonController

```
  public $components = array( 'Email', 'Session', 'RequestHandler', 'Cookie'); 
  //this is person/index
 public function index(){
       debug($this->Session->read("bunny");
 }
```

When I go to the url http://domian.org/person/index, that debug line is null. Shouldnt it print out "123456"?

Comment: Did you mean to have `function` in the line `public index()` ?

Comment: I've added it. Thanks. I'm still having the same errors though.

Comment: does it actually debug 'null', or is it not debugging anything?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say it bug but as far as i have worked on the cake php. I found that most of the people are facing the same problem use php default function here.

Use `session_start();` before filter function or use `ob_clean();` before filter function i think this may resolve your issue